# PHP session_start() no space left on device Debian 9.13

Tags: php, session, debian, apache2, php-7

I have a PHP 7.4 application that runs on Debian 9.13 Stretch.

If I run **df -h** I see the following result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           386M   39M  347M  11% /run
/dev/sda1        50G  9.7G   38G  21% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

If I run df -i it shows:

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            491092     313 490779    1% /dev
tmpfs           494055     357 493698    1% /run
/dev/sda1      3200000 3200000      0  100% /
tmpfs           494055       1 494054    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           494055       2 494053    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           494055      15 494040    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_8ov813u743ic7skcp70j98m160, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in /var/www/...

Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in /var/www/...

Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active in /var/www/...
```

If I run the following command in the sessions folder:

```
ls | wc -l
```

It returns 134 as the number of files.

If I clear everything inside the sessions folder the errors disappear.

What can I do to prevent these errors? Should I change the session storage location? Should I make other changes in the php.ini file? Should I change owner/write permissions for the sessions folder?

Comment: What does `df -i /` show?

Comment: It seems that /dev/sda1 is 100%. Any fix?

Comment: If I run: cd and go to the server's root folder it seems that I have millions of files randomly created. I will try to delete them.

Comment: You an reformat it to add more inodes. You have millions of tiny files.

Comment: You should also try to figure out what's creating them and stop it.

Comment: Thanks for the df -i suggestion. I will delete these files and try to find what creates them.